# Invokable interfaces with overloads

Tags: interface, typescript, overloading

I have multiple types that I want to associate an (external) function with. I've decided to hold them into a behind-the scenes array, along the lines of:

```
var labelGenerators : ILabelGenerator[] = []
```

where `ILabelGenerator` is supposed to be a general interface for the different shapes the types can have, something like:

```
interface ILabelGenerator{
  (container : SomeContainerObject, delta: IDeltaValues): string;
  (container : SomeContainerObject, x: number, y: number): string;
  (container : SomeContainerObject, x: Date, y: number): string;
}
```

Now, I do not know how to add an item to the `labelGenerators` array, because if I do something like:

```
labelGenerators[0] = (container:SomeContainerObject, x:number, y: number) => {
   return "label 0"; //the real code uses the parameters
}
```

I get a type `(container:SomeContainerObject, x:number, y: number) => string is not assignable to type ILabelGenerator` error.

How to work around this?
(I'm using TypeScript 1.3, but since I have around 10 shapes of the call, a 1.4 union type will be very unwieldy)

Comment: How does anyone do something useful with the `labelGenerators` array? It's impossible to inspect the functions to know which signature they should be invoked with.

Comment: This will be used internally and well documented (also the indices into the array come from an enumerator). So `labelGenerators[LabelType.TimeStamp](` provides me with all the overloads, and the developer is able to choose the "correct" one in a specific scenario. Also I get a compile error if I miss all of the implementations, which is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably avoid compiler errors since you tell explicitly TS:

```
labelGenerators[0] = <ILabelGenerator>(
     (container: SomeContainerObject, x: number, y: number) => { 
         return "label 0"; //the real code uses the parameters 
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your original interface doesn't say "it can be any of these", it says "it will be compatible with all of these" - to satisfy that you would have to use widened types or have all the appropriate overloads implemented.

The interface you want is "it will be *one* of these". When this is the case, you should actually create the interface that contains the actual contract. The only thing an implementation promises within a contract is that the first parameter is of type `SomeContainerObject`. As far as the additional parameters are concerned, all bets are off.

The contract is there to allow calling code to know what it can rely on. Therefore, I would use the following interface:

```
interface ILabelGenerator{
  (container: SomeContainerObject, ...additional: any[]): string;
}
```

The reason for using this interface is that this is all you promise about an implementation of `ILabelGenerator`.

For example, when you type the following...

```
labelGenerators[0](
```

You'll get an honest reflection of reality.

Your original interfaces over-promises, because it suggests "you can call your preferred signature". This version says "I have no idea what you should supply after your first argument". i.e. this is the truth!

Comment: Yes, it is a (type-safe) over-promise - and this would be a bad design for outward facing code (It's used internally and documented). However, it is helpful that `labelGenerators[0](` provides me with all the overloads, and the developer is able to choose the "correct" one in a specific scenario.
Also I get a compile error if I miss all of the implementations, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Since the second argument needs to be compatible with all signatures. Use x:any

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid, either in the interface definition, or in the function declaration. Invocation of the elements, once I get them in, works without problems, though.